# google chart treemap lable wrapping

Tags: word-wrap, treemap

I have the following code and I want to achieve that long lables are not beeing cut off, but rather wrapped into more lines.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Google Chart Treemap Example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="treemap-chart" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['treemap']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'ID');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Parent');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
      data.addRows([
        ['Root', null, 0],          
        ['Very long lable which shall be wrapped', 'Root', 0],    
        ['Child 1', 'Very long lable which shall be wrapped', 5],
        ['Child 2', 'Very long lable which shall be wrapped', 8], 
        ['Parent 2', 'Root', 0],   
        ['Child 3', 'Parent 2', 12],
        ['Child 4', 'Parent 2', 6]
      ]);

      var options = {
        minColor: '#f00',
        midColor: '#ddd',
        maxColor: '#0d0',
        headerHeight: 15,
        fontColor: 'black',
        showScale: true,
        allowHtml: true,
        textStyle: {
          fontSize: 20,
          bold: true,
          wordWrap: 'break-word',
          maxLines: 2,
        },
        maxDepth: 1,
      };

      var tree = new google.visualization.TreeMap(document.getElementById('treemap-chart'));
      tree.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried "wordWrap" but it is not working.

I also tried to adjust the google-visualization-treemap-label: directly

`.google-visualization-treemap-label { white-space: pre-wrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; }`